# Qt 5.10 - How to add a chart example to a layout

Tags: c++, qt, frontend, desktop

It's my very first experience with Qt so i hope its a basic question with a basic answer I couldn't find. I need to add a "custom" chart widget

> *(like in the following example: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtcharts-zoomlinechart-example.html)*

to some Qt container like **"layout" or "form"**. Its very straightforward when you have the widget in the toolbox and you use the designer but since it is a custom widget i cannot do that.

How do you do this in Qt creator?

Comment: The chart widget should inherit from QWidget and then promote this in the designer, [as documented](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-custom-widgets.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Chart class inherits from QWidget, you have two ways to do this:

1. In the Design mode, put a QWidget on your Window, or into a Layout. Then, right click on it and select "Promote to ...". There, write your class name in "Promoted class name".
2. In your window cpp file, write:

   ```
   YourChartClass* ycc = new YourChartClass(this);
   ycc.show();
   ```

   or

   ```
   YourChartClass* ycc = new YourChartClass();
   this->layout()->addWidget(ycc)
   ```

If your chart inherits from another class, and that class inherits from QWidget, the code lines are the same.